# Can server know the hostname of client in socket programming C

Tags: c, sockets, server, client

In socket programming communication between client and server. 
when the client sends a message to the server.

1. Can the server know or determine the hostname of the client?
2. Does it has to be passed manually by the client?
3. The normal way to pass message to server from client is `write(fd, clientMessage, sizeof(clientMessage));`. 
   Suppose there is some header information to be shared also like say hostname. 
   Does that has to be passed like this only? Or there is some better alternative?

Comment: It knows the IP, so it can query DNS.

Comment: ..assuming an appropriate DNS server is reachable.

Comment: If you have a connected socket (like a TCP socket) then you can use the `getpeername` function to get the "name" (address) of the peer (the other end of the connection). From that you can use e.g. (the obsolete) `gethostbyaddr` function, or the modern alternative `getaddrinfo`.

Comment: How you pass a message from the client to the server depends on the communication protocol. If additional information is part of the protocol you have to send it as well (somehow). Partial `read` or `write` operations can occur, e.g. your code may want to write 10 bytes but only 5 get written in the first call. In such a case you would have to repeat the `write` call with the remaning data.

Comment: can we read and write using structs ? I tried passing `write(fd, _message, sizeof(_message)); `  But threw an error - `typedef struct message {
 int transactionLength;
 char epochTime[20];
 char hostname[100];
} message;`

Comment: extern ssize_t write (int __fd, const void *__buf, size_t __n) __wur;
 error: incompatible type for argument 2 of ‘write’

Comment: @EugeneSh.: DNS is not reliable to get the hostname from the IP address. Things like `gethostbyaddr` rely on PTR records which map IP address to a name. These don't need to exist in the first place and they might actually lie, i.e. a client could claim to be google.com this way.

Comment: Re: passing the struct, you could cast it to an array of bytes (e.g. (char*)) and it will write all the bytes contained in the struct.  This means you'll have to make sure the other side knows what it's receiving so it can reconstitute the struct on the other end.  In particular, you'll want to ensure you get the same endianness for the `int` member.  You'll also want to make sure the receiver knows when a struct is coming so it can read the appropriate number of bytes to rebuild the struct.  (There is no guarantee all bytes of the struct will be read on a single call to `read`, for example.)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "*..., or the modern alternative getaddrinfo*" - you meant `getnameinfo()` instead.  `getaddrinfo()` converts an IP/hostname string into a binary IP address.  `getnameinfo()` converts a binary IP address into a hostname string.

Comment: @pensee "*can we read and write using structs ?*" - yes (*with care*). Your `write()` failed to compile because `_message` is not a pointer. Try `write(fd, &_message, sizeof(_message));` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ah yeah that's the one... :)

Comment: want to add one more info. I think i confused people. Although the comments were helpful. By hostname I mean the string you get when you type the hostname command on linux terminal. A machine could run multiple client programs and there will be only one server program. like the normal client server using sockets in c

Answer (score 0):

> Can the server know or determine the hostname of the client?

No. The server has only the clients IP address. While it can try a [reverse DNS lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) the information returned by this are unreliable, i.e. there might be no DNS PTR record setup in the first place or the PTR record might just claim an arbitrary mapping between IP and hostname, like claiming to be google.com.

> Does it has to be passed manually by the client?

There is no automatic way in TCP to do this. But like with a PTR record - the information is not reliable since the client can claim to be anything.

> The normal way to pass message to server from client is write(fd, clientMessage, sizeof(clientMessage));. ... Does that has to be passed like this only ...

It does not matter how it gets passed. All what matters is that client and server agree on the same way, so that the server can actually extract the information from the data.